# Custom calendar previous and next button issue

Tags: java, android

I'm writing an application with a custom calendar and I'm trying to add previous and next month button. The problem is that when I use `calendar.add(Calendar.MONTH, 1);` it adds 2 months instead of 1. When I write `calendar.add(Calendar.MONTH, -1);` it's even weirder, because it ADDS 3 DAYS and after that it stops working at all.

I tried  `calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, month + 1);` and it works properly with months, but it mixes years. Eg. when it's December 2019 the next month is January 2021. When I decrease months it's worse, because when it's November it adds a year. I added:

```
if(calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH) == Calendar.JANUARY){
                    calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, year + 1);
                }
```

And then the next button works properly. I tried that with the previous button also:

```
if(calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH) == Calendar.DECEMBER){
                    calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, year - 1);
                }
```

But it still adds a year in November. But when I change December to November in this code it substracts a year, eg when it's December 2019 the next month is November 2018 and it's also incorect. Any ideas?

```
private void setPreviousButtonClickEvent() {

        layout.bringToFront();
        previousButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, day);
                calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, month - 1);
                if(calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH) == Calendar.DECEMBER){
                    calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, year - 1);
                }
                fillTheCalendar();
            }
        });
    }

    private void setNextButtonClickEvent() {

        layout.bringToFront();
        nextButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, day);
                calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, month + 1);
                if(calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH) == Calendar.JANUARY){
                    calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, year + 1);
                }
                fillTheCalendar();
            }
        });
    }
```

```
 private void fillTheCalendar() {

        views = new ArrayList<CalendarViews>();
        calendar = (Calendar) calendar.clone();
        @SuppressLint("SimpleDateFormat") SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMMM, yyyy");
        long currentDate = calendar.getTimeInMillis();
        String todaysDate = sdf.format(currentDate);
        date.setText(todaysDate);
        // determine the cell for current month's beginning
        year = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        day = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
        month = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);

        calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, month);
        int monthBeginningCell = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) - 2;
        // move calendar backwards to the beginning of the week
        calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, -monthBeginningCell);

        while (views.size() < DAYS_COUNT) {

            dayOfMonth = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
            views.add(new CalendarViews(calendar.getTime(), dayOfMonth, 0, "event"));

            calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
        }
        final CalendarAdapter adapter = new CalendarAdapter(getContext(), views);
        gridView.setAdapter(adapter);


    }
```

Comment: I fixed the previous button like this: if(calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH) == Calendar.NOVEMBER){
                    calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
                } It works properly, but I don't understand why it behaved like this.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is that one should not use java.util.Calendar. One should use java.time:)